# Can I turn on IE 10 Compatibility View using JavaScript or HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-10

How can I turn on IE 10 Compatibility View programmatically in Javascript or HTML?

I just added the following meta tag within the `<head>` tag, but it is not working.

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
```

Is there any way to do the same thing in JS?

Comment: what meta tag have you added ?

Comment: i used only following code,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I checked the compatibility mode article on msdn - [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/hh920756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Your meta tag is still the method for enabling compatibility mode in IE 10 and IE 9.

As long as you have:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
    <!-- Other meta tags etc. -->
<head>
```

Then it should work. You could try making the http-equiv value  case sensitive (at the moment you've set it to lowercase).

Also, to answer your question about JS, you can detect whether the browser is in compatibility mode by comparing the browser engine with the browser version for IE. However, this involves browser version detection, which tends to be a bit unreliable. Also, there isn't a way for you to set the user's compatibility mode in JS. So, for the moment at least, you'll have to stick with the meta tags.

I hope this helps.

---

A good plugin to allow you to view http header information is [IEhttpheaders](http://www.blunck.info/iehttpheaders.html). Just download it from that link & install. Then, when you start IE, go to the tools menu and select 'DisplayIEhttpHeaders...'. When you visit your site it will list the header response. If you modify your answer to include the response, then we can see if it's the problem.

Comment: thanks for your kind reply, i already tried above your points, but it does not changed automatically, i already read the msdn articles and reviews, something missing in our code.

Comment: @raja: It might be that your server is sending an `X-UA-Compatible` HTTP header with a different value to your `<meta>` tag. I think the HTTP header will override the meta tag, if present. Might be worth checking that too.

Comment: @raja Paul may be right. You can use one of the many plugins that are around that allow you to view http header responses - I've modified my answer to include a link to one of them.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite , Peter thanks all, i will try with your solution, and get you all.

Comment: This worked for me as well, have an upvote. For others who might try and not have it working: don't use multiple instances of the X-UA-Compatible tag for IE. In my case `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">` was working, `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE9">` was not. Also take care: it's NOT changing the IE browser mode to display rendering in IE10-Compatibility mode, but it changes the "document mode" to be IE9/8/7-compatible.

Comment: Two corrections: 1) [`X-UA-Compatible` **isn't** case sensitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx), but must appear in `<head>` before all other elements (except `<title>` and other `<meta>` elements), and 2) [`document.documentMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/cc196988(v=vs.85).aspx) exposes the current document mode in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You say “I just added the following meta tag within the header tag”. Do you mean:

1. The `<header>` tag
2. The `<head>` tag?

The `x-ua-compatible` meta tag does need to go inside the `<head>` tag, not a `<header>` tag.

Comment: sorry, i added only inside the <head> tag. but its not working , any other way to solve ?

Comment: @raja: are you sure it isn’t working? How are you confirming that IE 10 isn’t in `EmulateIE7` mode? Could you put up a test page somewhere on the internet that we can look at?

Comment: i got the solution. i used in this in server base.

Comment: @Elayaraja: thanks for getting back to us, although I'm not quite clear what you mean by "i used in this in server base".

Comment: Instead of placing Emulate in all Servlet pages, i have invoke from the server.

Comment: @Elayaraja: oh I see: in the HTTP headers?

Comment: @ELAYARAJA & paul so what is the final solution in the server side ? could you elaborate it ?

Comment: when viewing the page from the server, the Emulation shows the document mode as '7 (Default)' via Intranet compatibility settings but, when running the page in my machine, the Emulation shows document mode as '8 (Default)' via x-UA-Compatibility meta tag. How can i force document mode to be '8' always ?

Comment: @yathirigan: “always” is tricky. You can include `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">` inside the page’s `<head>` tag, which will make IE display the page in IE 8 mode when it’s loaded from somewhere other than a web server. However, if that page is served from a server, and the server sends a different X-UA-Compatible value in an HTTP header, that value will override the HTML tag.

Comment: @yathirigan: and then [both the HTTP header and HTML tag can be overridden by a couple of settings in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342348/the-html5-doctype-is-not-triggering-standards-mode-in-ie8/13342445#13342445), like the “Display intranet sites in Compatibility View” setting that you mentioned. I don’t believe those settings can be overridden from code.