# Force IE10 to run in IE10 Compatibility View?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have an app that is broke in IE10 but runs fine in IE10 Compatibility View. A quick google results in the

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
<!-- plus variations such as emulate, quirks, 7, 8, 9 --->
```

tag. Some MS documentation on the tag is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj676915.aspx). If you press F12 you can see that it changes the document mode. I need it to change the **Browser Mode** to Internet Explorer 10 Compatibility View. Is there any tag that will do this?

[image]

**UPDATE**
I need to mention that I have tried all of the following doctypes and none of them work. I think the only way to get this to work in IE10 is to use Compatibility View.

```
<!--
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
    TRIED NO DOCTYPE AT ALL TOO
-->
```

Comment: I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: The best solution would be to fix the issues you are having that make you need compatibility view. That will be more sustainable going forward, and likely improve performance. What issues in IE10 standards more are you having? Maybe we can fix those.

Comment: If you could describe the issues which occur when not running in compatibility mode, those could be fixed. It's hard to tell what you mean by "broke in IE10"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641503/can-i-turn-on-ie-10-compatibility-view-using-javascript-or-html  
Basically, make sure the server isn't sending a different X-UA_Compatible in the headers.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to set the compatibility mode *in the browser itself* and *not in the html* do the following

1. Open IE 10
2. Press the ALT Key to bring up the IE Menubar
3. Click on the Tools menu
4. Click on compatibility view setting.
5. Clicks check the box; display all the websites in compatibility view
    **or**
6. Add only the desired websites to the compatibility view

As shown in the image below. The website should then open up with IE 10 Compatibility view.

[image]

Comment: this is the only way it seems to make "Compatibility View" work.

Answer (score 11):

You can try :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
```

Just like you tried before, but caution:

**It seems like the X-UA-Compatible tag has to be the first tag in the  < head > section**

If this conclusion is correct, then I believe it is undocumented in Microsoft’s blogs/msdn (and if it is documented, then it isn’t sticking out well enough from the docs). Ensuring that this was the first meta tag in the  forced IE9 to switch to IE8 mode successfully

Comment: The requirement is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj676915.aspx

Comment: This won't change the browser mode but the document mode. I don't know if there is any difference but so far I have only been able to switch the later using meta tags. On the other hand the later was sufficient to get the pages I had trouble with to run again.

Comment: Where do I have to put this line?

Comment: In the <head> section of your HTML (Sorry for the delay)

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem, this - "meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">" works great in IE8 and IE9, but not in IE10. There is a bug in the server browser definition files that shipped with .NET 2.0 and .NET 4, namely that they contain definitions for a certain range of browser versions. But the versions for some browsers (like IE 10) aren't within those ranges any more. Therefore, ASP.NET sees them as unknown browsers and defaults to a down-level definition, which has certain inconveniences, like that it does not support features like JavaScript.

My thanks to Scott Hanselman for this fix.

Here is the link -

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

This MS KP fix just adds missing files to the asp.net on your server. I installed it and rebooted my server and it now works perfectly. I would have thought that MS would have given this fix a wider distribution.

Rick

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.  The problem is a bug in MSIE 10, so telling people to fix their issues isn't helpful.  Neither is telling visitors to your site to add your site to compatibility view, bleh.  In my case, the problem was that the following code displayed no text:

```
document.write ('<P>'); 
document.write ('Blah, blah, blah... ');
document.write ('</P>');
```

After much trial and error, I determined that removing the <P> and </P> tags caused the text to appear properly on the page (thus, the problem IS with document mode rather than browser mode, at least in my case).   Removing the <P> tags when userAgent is MSIE is not a "fix" I want to put into my pages.

The solution, as others have said, is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML whatever doctype you're using....> 
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">
  <TITLE>Blah...
```

Yes, the meta tag has to be the FIRST tag after HEAD.

Answer (score 4):

While you should fix your site so it works without Compatibility View, try putting the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag as the very first thing after the opening `<head>`, *before* the title

Answer (score 1):

See here:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194687/how-the-compatibility-view-in-ie-works-behind-the-scenes

Use

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10">`

I just tried it and it showed IE10 compatibility mode in the debug window.

Answer (score 1):

The `X-UA-Compatible` `meta` element only changes the Document mode, not the Browser mode. The Browser mode is chosen before the page is requested, so there is no way to include any markup, JavaScript or such to change this. While the Document mode falls back to older standards and quirks modes of the rendering engine, the Browser mode just changes things like how the browser identifies, such as the User Agent string.

If you’d like to change the Browser mode for all users (rather than changing it manually in the tools or through the settings), the only way (AFAICT) is to get your site added to Microsoft’s Copat View List. This is maintained by Microsoft to apply overrides to sites which break. There is [information on how to remove your site from the compat view list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699485%28v=vs.85%29.ASPX#removal), but none I can find to request that you're added.

The preferred method however is to try to fix any issues on the site first, as when you don’t run using the latest document and browser mode you can not take advantage of improvements in the browser, such as increased performance.

Comment: For many web applications fixing the issues is not an option. Not when the solution is to replace the software completely and a fix is needed until then.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the IE 5 quirks compatibility mod (is the default IE10 compatibility view)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">
```

important: set in the top of your iframe structure (if you use iframe structure)

more info [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/12/14/interoperable-html5-quirks-mode-in-ie10.aspx)