# Internet Explorer - How to force compatibility mode for certain sites?

Tags: internet-explorer, ie-compatibility-mode

I would like to force IE10 to render certain sites from my intranet in IE9 mode.

I have tried using the local compatibility list to no avail (%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IECompatData\iecompatdata.xml). I have tried adding the following entry into that file:

<domain docMode="EmulateIE9">projects.mycompany.com</domain>

Is anybody aware if this is possible? Or maybe there's an add-on for inserting a doctype on the fly?

I could also use fiddler for that, but I would like to know if there's no simpler solution.

**Update: to clarify, I need a solution that works client-side. I have no access to the servers. I might want, for instance, to modify the headers (insert a DOCTYPE) in a certain page from http://abc.com, to which I have no access. I could do that with fiddler or something like GreaseMonkey (Trixie for IE), but I am first looking for an easier solution before dirtying my hands.**

Answer (score 8):

You can specify sites for the Compatibility list (including subdomains) by doing the following:

1) Open up Local Group Policy Editor (<kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> & type `gpedit.msc`)

[image: Windows Key+R->gpedit.msc]

2) Go to:

> `Computer Configuration/Administrative Template/Windows Components/Internet      Explorer/Compatibility View`

[image: Local Group Policy Editor]

3) Edit the `Use Policy List of Quirks Mode sites`, enable it and add sites to the list of sites

[image: List]

4) Reboot and try those sites

Comment: Didn't work for me. I tried adding to both "Use Policy List of Quirks Mode sites" and "Use Policy List of Internet Explorer 7 sites" to no avail. I always get the user-agent "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)". I'm doing it on a Windows 7 machine with IE10. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks. But the question is how to insert this on certain pages client-side. I have no access to the servers. I'm updating the original question to make this clear.

Answer (score 2):

PLease see this [Force IE10 to run in IE10 Compatibility View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387325/force-ie10-to-run-in-ie10-compatibility-view)

I'm using this solution:

---

If you want to set the compatibility mode in the browser itself and not in the html do the following

1. Open IE 10
2. Press the ALT Key to bring up the IE Menubar
3. Click on the Tools menu
4. Click on compatibility view setting.
5. Clicks check the box; display all the websites in compatibility view or
6. Add only the desired websites to the compatibility view

As shown in the image below. The website should then open up with IE 10 Compatibility view.

---

Note: In my case i have many web but i have to special site were the first domain was .net and now change to .net.ar

when I add the domain into view list example:

www.example.domain.net.ar

www.example2.domain.net.ar

The problem was the second domain was created since bigining in domain.net.ar and the first one was create first domain.net

I add the two domain:

> domain.net
>   domain.net.ar

Why I add the two domain?

Because when the system charge the url example.domain.net.ar not up with compatibility view activated. 
That why I add the domain.net also because that web was created with that domain. now is working both.

That fix the issue.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

Press the "Alt" key, when the menu appears, go to Tools -> Compatibility View Settings. You can add certain sites you want to have display in compatibility view there.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you can't add single sites there, but only entire domains. So, if I try to add "home.microsoft.com" there it will automatically strip away the "home" part. I need a setting that would affect single sites.

Answer (score -1):

If you dont want to use "gpedit.msc" you CAN also achive the same results by doing the following.

In ie 10 or above

click tools (the cog) -> internet option -> security Tab
Highligh "Local Intranet" and click "Sites" Button.
In the dialogue that appears click the "Advanced" button
Add the full path of the site you wish to be in compatibility mode "www.example.domain.net.ar" or "www.example2.domain.net.ar"

Close all the dialogue windows untill you are back with IE

click tools (The Cog) -> compatibility view settings and make sure "Display intranet sites in Compatability View" is checked

walla your subdomain now works in compatibility view.

warning !!! There are security issue around this for examples local intranet site usually have lower IE security settings so dont go using this technique for sites you do not control!

Comment: It was already mentioned in a previous comment that it works for subdomains. The problem is with individual sites.

Comment: The above works for subdomains on diffrent root domain.. maybe our definitions of 'diffrent sites' is not the same as all of your above examples are indeed subdomains of domain.ner.ar ??

Comment: @jhrecife if you mean "if I try to add "home.microsoft.com" there it will automatically strip away the "home" part."
My solution does NOT strip away the "home" part