# How to launch a local html page in IE10 in compatibility mode?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have a set of old html+JScript pages that are loaded from a local hard drive only. They used to work in previous versions of IE, but IE10 had something changed and it doesn't work anymore. I didn't write the code, so I don't think it's feasible to see what is broken, but it seems to work if I change IE into compatibility mode.

So I was curious, is there a command line parameter to launch IE in compatibility mode without altering the html file itself?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387325/force-ie10-to-run-in-ie10-compatibility-view for possible answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to set compatibility settings to IE8, try

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

in head tag of html.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Except that now I need to apply it to about 100+ files... That's why I was looking for a command line parameter solution :(

Answer (score 0):

Under the Tools Menu bar, click on Compatibility Mode Settings. You can add all the sites where you want to run in compatibility mode there. More info [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/internet-explorer/use-compatibility-view#ie=ie-10)

Comment: It's a bunch of local files, so there're no particular web sites here.

Comment: Are you running these local html files through a server such as IIS? If you are running them in a server, you can add meta tag values via server settings.

Comment: There is also a setting in the same window to display all pages in compatibility mode

Comment: No. I'm not using IIS. They are run as a part of a custom-made software. The software itself is somewhat old and is not updated any longer.