# CSS3 effects only work in some Internet Explorers

Tags: css

I just had a client tell me that CSS3 styles and effects are not working on some Internet Explorers and in some they work fine. They are all IE 10 which is why I am at a loss. How could this work in some IE 10 and not others? The machines I am on they all work fine but I used teamviewer to see the problem and it is in fact not working on this particular IE 10.

The main problem is the main nav links "products", "support" and "community" all have drop downs. These drop downs work fine in every browser except for some machines my client tested in IE 10. [This page here is what I am attaching screen shots of](http://hauppauge.com/gaming/index.htm)

[image: IE 10 doesn't work]Here in this screen shot (taken using teamviewer) you can see how the down arrows are missing after the text (the arrows are a webfont), and the drop downs do not appear.

Here is a screen shot of how it should look :[image] You see the webfont icons (down arrows) and the drop down appear on rollover.

The css files are [HERE](http://hauppauge.com/css/gaming/nav-menu-gaming.css) and [HERE](http://hauppauge.com/css/gaming/hcw_styles_gaming.css)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I just cannot figure this out.

Thank You!

Comment: I'd bet one IE10 is in compatibility mode and the other isn't

Comment: Yes that is exactly the problem, it was in compatibility mode. Is there a way to avoid this happening?

Comment: Not sure exactly, try googling it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387325/force-ie10-to-run-in-ie10-compatibility-view