# Report is not displaying IE 10 and above

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, reporting-services, internet-explorer-10, reportviewer

I've designed an SSRS report in SQL Server 2008 R2. I'm displaying the report in an MVC application using the ReportViewer control.

It is working fine in Firefox and Chrome and below IE10 browsers. However, in IE 10 the report is not getting displayed.

If I changed browser mode to IE10 Compat View in the IE Developer Tools (F12), it is working fine. Please check the attached images:

[image: without compat]

[image: with compat]

I have gone through several forum's posts, most of them suggesting to keep an meta tag in master file:

```xml
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIEX">
```

where `X` is the IE Version. Some other forum threads suggests to install Service Pack 2 for SQL Server, which I tried but still no luck.

We can not suggest to end user (some of whom may be non-technical) to change the browser mode in Developer Tools.

Please help me display the report in latest IE browsers (IE10 or above) by default.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387325/force-ie10-to-run-in-ie10-compatibility-view .. see this link it may help

Comment: Hello HbV2, I tried all those by changing browser mode or adding our site to compatibility list which have to do manually by end user. And also i added the meta tag which changes the "document mode" not the "browser mode".

Comment: Are you fully patched up?  I can't remember which versions did what, but some of the newer IE compatibility issues have been addressed in some versions of SSRS...

Comment: Can you move to .net 4.5 on your server? it has advanced support for identifying browser agent tags for IE 11/12.

Answer (score -1):

I've had a similar problem plaguing me for awhile now, and I've never truly been able to get IE10+ to display a report without using compatibility mode. I did discover a workaround though.

Instead of displaying the report in the Report Viewer, I set the display mode to open the report in another program. It appears that your report could be exported to Excel, so I would set the report to open in Excel.

In c# it would look something like this:

`rp.ReportDisplayMode = "Excel";`