# Forcing IE10 Quirk mode for all version of Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, doctype, quirks-mode

I have recently developed a responsive website using bootstrap, it's working fine on all browser including IE10, however when i go into IE 9 from developers tool, website starts breaking, because the document mode changes to IE 5 Quirks.

So i would like to keep the document mode to just IE10 Quirks mode, because with this in place my website works on all version of IE (7,8,9).

Can anyone tell me how to keep the IE10 Quirks mode for every version of IE browser.

Comment: I really don't follow... that's like saying How can I make IE7 render as IE10, which it obviously cannot do because it doesn't have IE10's rendering engine.  IE10 can render as IE7, but you can't do the other way around.

Comment: If this is the reason, then document mode should also not switch automatically to IE5 Quirks when we change it to IE 9 from developers Tool.

Comment: I think you're confusing DevTools emulation with the actual IE7, 8 or 9.  While the F12 tool may allow you to set Browser Mode to IE7 and manually force document mode to IE10, that won't work that way in the REAL IE7 and there is no way to make that work.

Comment: ok, but is there any other options with which i can make my ensure that my website will work on all versions of IE, atleast versions greater than 8, my website has been developed in bootstrap, i have also used <!Doctype html> tag, so that it would always run website under regular quirks mode

Comment: Yes, test your code.  Validate it against W3C html validators.  Test it on real copies of multiple browsers.  Fix problems you find.  This is what being a web developer is all about.  There is no shortcut.  Web Development is hard.

Comment: One thing you can do is serve an x-ua-compatible header set to `ie=edge`.  While this doesn't retrofit older versions of IE with features supported by more recent versions, it does tell IE6 and later to render a page in the best mode supported for that version.  Generally, this is standards mode (as opposed to quirks mode).  To learn more, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force IE10 to run in IE10 Compatibility View?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387325/force-ie10-to-run-in-ie10-compatibility-view)