# ie7 standards document mode triggered

Tags: html, doctype

I am using the HTML5 doctype on my page;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Now it triggers the standards mode when viewing my page on IE9 or IE10. 
However when I try to view the page in IE8, it actually triggers the document mode as "IE7 standards mode"

What exactly is the issue and how do I fix it?
I want IE8 standards mode to be triggered when viewing my page on IE8.

Comment: Try restarting the browser. IE remembers some weird stuff when you go playing with doc-types.

Comment: I did try that...But it does not work....Based on the scenario I have mentioned, should IE8 standards mode not be the one that gets triggered ?

Comment: I am just asking this as on the page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh779632.aspx it says "This markup triggers standards mode in Internet Explorer 9 and 10."

Comment: I think so. Is this a public URL? I might be able to check it out myself.

Comment: No..It is actually a secure URL...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342348/the-html5-doctype-is-not-triggering-standards-mode-in-ie8