# Force IE Browser Mode into Compatibility mode?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, compatibility, doctype

I noticed something interesting about my website. It displays correctly when I have the meta tag  `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">` in IE 8 and 7, but in IE 9 and 10, it does not display correctly. However, they are seen correctly when I go to Developer Tools and set the browser mode to IE 10 or IE 9 Compatible mode.

I was wondering, is there a way you can force IE 10 or IE 9 to automatically view the page in Compatibility mode without changing the mode in Developer Tools? If so, is there a `Doctype` or `meta` tag that can do this for me? I've done some research and I've only found `Doctypes` that allow you to view things in only standard mode, but I haven't found any `Doctype` that can allow you to view something in Cmpatability mode. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [The HTML5 doctype is not triggering standards mode in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342348/the-html5-doctype-is-not-triggering-standards-mode-in-ie8)

Answer (score 1):

There’s a couple of settings in IE 8 that can cause pages to render in Compatibility Mode, regardless of the page’s HTML content or HTTP headers:

Page > Compatibility View Settings

If “Display intranet sites in Compatibility View” is checked, then IE will render all sites on the local network in compatibility view. (This has happened to me a few times during development.)

If “Include updated website lists from Microsoft” is checked, then IE will download a list of websites from Microsoft and render them all in compatibility view.

If “Display all websites in Compatibility View” is checked, then, well, you can guess what happens.

Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Browsing

If “Automatically recover from page layout errors with Compatibility View” is checked, then IE will sometimes switch to compatibility view if it thinks a page’s layout is broken.

And, finally, if you navigate to a page and then click on Page > Compatibility View (or click on the compatibility view icon in the address bar), then that page will be rendered in compatibility view.

So, although it’s worth putting X-UA-Compatible in there and using a doctype like the HTML5 one (so that your intentions are clear), always check these settings first when testing.

Source: [The HTML5 doctype is not triggering standards mode in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342348/the-html5-doctype-is-not-triggering-standards-mode-in-ie8)